# How to parse String Unirest Response

Tags: javascript, java, unirest

I have a unirest request that receives a String response and I'm having trouble parsing its result. I did a research but all I saw was tutorials on how to parse a json request which is apparently not the one I need. Anyway, the request looks like this:

```
public static String getToken() {
    //HttpResponse<String> response = null;
    try {
        //Unirest request
        HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.post("http://api.nuvelco.com/token")
                .header("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .header("cache-control", "no-cache")
                .body("grant_type=password&username=demo_user&password=demo_pass&client_id=paymentApp")
                .asString();

        //attempts I took to print a proper response on the logs
        logger.info("RAW BODY: " + response.getRawBody());          
        logger.info("BODY: " + response.getBody());
        logger.info("STATUS: " + response.getStatus());

        return null;
    } catch (UnirestException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

The response is supposed to look like this:

```
{
 "access_token": "sample_access_token",
 "token_type": "bearer",
 "expires_in": 3599,
 "refresh_token": "sample_refresher_token",
 "as:client_id": "paymentApp",
 "username": "demo_user",
 ".issued": "Thu, 08 Jun 2017 06:19:50 GMT",
 ".expires": "Thu, 08 Jun 2017 07:19:50 GMT"
}
```

But somehow, I always get this response:

```
<html>
    <head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
        <center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
        <hr><center>nginx/1.13.4</center>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure if its relevant, but I'm using a javascript to call the Java function `getToken()`. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Won't adding `Accept: application/json` to request headers help?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm embarrassingly new at this. Where am I supposed to add the `Accept application/json`? I tried adding it to the `Unirest.post` but there's no accept in the suggested methods

Comment: @Uzi In your example this would be `.header("Accept", "application/json")`

Also, it seems that you're getting a 404 so I'd make sure the post request is sent to a proper address first

Comment: I forgot to reply about the 404 reply. That's actually one of my problems. I always get the 404 error even when all my credentials are correct. I can't seem to get through

Answer (score 0):

Try add `/` to url in `Unirest.post("http://api.nuvelco.com/token")`. 
Some like this:

```
Unirest.post("http://api.nuvelco.com/token/")
```